# Why does R paste more decimals than have been rounded, but only sometimes?

Tags: r, floating-point

I know floating point numbers are strange, but I haven't come across this exact issue before. I have a vector of numbers in R. I see how many are bigger than zero, and I take the mean of this to get the proportion above zero. I assign the number to an object after rounding it. When I go to paste it, somehow the numbers come back. I would `dput` the vector, but it is too long to do so, but here's the `head` and `str`:

```
> head(x)
[1] 0.1616631 0.2117250 0.1782197 0.1791657 0.2067048 0.2042075
> str(x)
 num [1:4000] 0.162 0.212 0.178 0.179 0.207 ...
```

Now here's where I run into issues:

```
> y <- round(mean(x > 0) * 100, 1)

> y
[1] 99.7

> str(y)
 num 99.7

> paste(100 - y, "is the inverse")
[1] "0.299999999999997 is the inverse"
```

But it doesn't behave the same if I don't subtract from 100:

```
> paste(y, "is it pasted")
[1] "99.7 is it pasted"
```

I know I could put `round` right into the `paste` command or use `sprintf`, and I know how floats are represented in R, but **I'm specifically wondering *why* it occurs for the former situation and not the latter**? I cannot get a reproducible example, either, because I cannot get a randomly-generated vector to behave in the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: @dan04 Thanks! I've read that thread before, but it seems to me like `paste` should treat both `y` and `100 - y` the same then. To be more specific, why does it print the decimals for `100 - y`, but not `y`?

Comment: It appears that R's default floating-point stringification uses the minimum number of decimal places that can recreate the original IEEE 754 `double` value.  A literal like `99.7` (which is actually 99.7000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125) will round-trip as-is.  OTOH, `100 - 99.7` evaluates to 0.2999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875, which is not the same as `0.3` (actually 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's rounding error, but in this case R is not handling it nicely.

Any representation of floating-point numbers in R is done as `double`, which means 53 bits of precision, approximately 16 digits. That's also for the `99.7`, you can see where it breaks down:

```
print(99.7, digits=16) # works fine
print(99.7, digits=17) # Adds a 3 at the end on my platform
```

That will be always a limit, which you are warned for when specifying it in print (in the docs).

But when you do calculations, any rounding error remains absolute, meaning your expected value of .3 has an **absolute** error that is just as big, but that is **relatively** 300 times larger. Therefore it "fails"  with less significant digits:

```
print(100-99.7, digits=14) # works fine
print(100-99.7, digits=15) # Allready rounding error at digits=15
```

Now `paste` passes any number to the function `as.character`, which (in this case unfortunately) does not look at any options you've set, it always uses a default value of 15 significant digits.

To solve it, you can use `format` to specify the desired number of digits:

```
paste(format(100 - y, digits=14), "is the inverse")
```